# How to query a json string in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I want to get a specific string from a column. How can I get that.

Here is the json with column name json with table name `my_table`

I want to fetch `"extensionAttribute.simSerial": "310240000029929"`.

```
{
  "name": "urn:imei:930000001801583",
  "type": "DEVICE",
  "sourceId": "P-n1000USCqT4",
  "consumers": "CDM",
  "crudStatus": {
    "status": "SUCCESS",
    "operation": "UPDATE"
  },
  "targetName": "urn:imei:930000001801583",
  "deviceTypeId": "dgs11b74714f7020ctoogu3zfugc6",
  "createdUserId": "a8aacc5d978d494eb54ae4243e714646",
  "onboardStatus": "DONE",
  "consrStatus": "",
  "deviceTypeName": "performance_device_type_2",
  "lwm2mPskSecret": "49443",
  "createdUserName": "manager",
  "bootstrapRequest": true,
  "lwm2mPskIdentity": "urn:imei:930000001801583",
  "boostrapPskSecret": "49443",
  "deviceTypeVersion": 1,
  "lastUpdatedUserId": "",
  "lwm2mSecurityMode": "psk",
  "consumersForUpdate": "",
  "bootstrapPskIdentity": "urn:imei:930000001801583",
  "pureCoapSecurityMode": "NONE",
  "bootstrapSecurityMode": "psk",
  "extensionAttribute.imsi": "310240000029929",
  "extensionAttribute.msisdn": "310240000029929",
  "extensionAttribute.simSerial": "310240000029929",
  "extensionAttribute.msisdnStatus": "active"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

You can do it as follows:

```
select column_name->>'extensionAttribute.simSerial' as simSerial from my_table;
```

where `column_name` is your column name in a table.

If you will have JSON with higher depth you can do something like:

```
column_name->'key_in_json'->'another_key_in_json'->>'last_key_in_json'
```

---

**Manual**

[JSON Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

[PostgreSQL JSON Tutorial](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/)